# Code Signing Error Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I just updated my xcode to 4.3.3 and it starts giving me this error on all my projects which were working fine previously. I can Build everything, but when i do: XCode> Product> Archive i get the error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain.

In my build-settings i have already chosen a valid keychain which is present on my system and visible through Keychain access. 
WHat the???  I tried cleaning derived data but no use....

Can someone please help......

Comment: you can just redownload another certificate. delete the existing in your machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've selected the valid signing setting not just in the PROJECT, but also in the TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the issue with the profiles. Remove all the Provisioning Profiles currently from the organizer and try use freshly downloaded one. Hope this helps you out there.